# AWS ELB + NGINX for rails app

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb

If I'm using Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer for a Rails app, do I need to put an Nginx reverse proxy between the app and the ELB?

Comment: That depends. Does rails include a web server? Do you need to do any caching or URL rewriting? Do you want additional flexibility? Why are you using an ELB if you only have one server? They're meant to spread the load across many servers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options) on Stack Overflow will give you a lot of background on Rails and web servers.

In short:

- Yes you need a web server for rails, but that's not Nginx
- No you don't need a reverse proxy
- Yes, you could benefit from having Nginx in your stack, mostly to give you flexibility for things like rewrites, caching, proxying, etc
- If you only have one web server an ELB is adding to your costs without offering significant advantages. However if you think you'll need to scale to multiple servers later it's probably not a bad idea to start with an ELB. You can always change DNS to do a gradual migration from a single elastic IP to an ELB later though.